# How to get all middle items in cards of 3 columns?

Tags: javascript, react-native, math

I have an array of cards and want to get all the middle cards on the list and apply background color for them.

[image: shot]

if we explain it we have the index
like this

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

so the targetted index is

```
1 4 7 etc
```

So I guess there's a formula to get it but I don't get it.

the current example code here

```
backgroundColor: index % 2 === 1 ? '#f00' : '#0f199a',
```

Comment: you mean `index % 3 === 1` surely. since 1 + 3 == 4 and 4 + 3 = 7 ... up by three at a time

Comment: @Bravo UH UH God! should I take math course :(

Comment: but that could be done in CSS `??? { background-color: #0f199a} ???:nth-child(3n+1) { background #f00 }` where `???` is whatever selects those "cards"

Comment: it's react-native stuff (FlatList) I don't know how should apply this on it

Comment: Oh, OK - yeah, should've noted the react-native tag - sorry

Comment: @Bravo Thanks 

Comment: best thing about my username ... even if people are criticising me it sounds like they're applauding me ... Bravo!! :p

Answer (score 0):

```css
backgroundColor: index % 3 === 1 ? '#f00' : '#0f199a'
```

should do the trick. So the operator here is the math modulus, or *remainder*, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder.

Comment: I think the OP knows what the operator is - he just used the wrong number, 2 instead of 3

Comment: Maybe, then again > So I guess there's a formula to get it but I don't get it.

Comment: Sure, that doesn't mean OP doesn't know what the operator does - :p just a thought (I didn't downvote, no idea why anyone would)